# Tensorflow C++ how to feed list?

Tags: c++, tensorflow

I'm trying to feed 'list' into tensorflow C++ model referencing,
https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/label_image/main.cc

My code is:

```
int main() {
  string graph_path = "tensorflow/examples/data/output_graph.pb";
  std::unique_ptr<tensorflow::Session> session;
  Status load_graph_status = LoadGraph(graph_path, &session);
  if (!load_graph_status.ok()) {
    LOG(ERROR) << load_graph_status;
    return -1;
  }
  string A = "OpNameC";
  Tensor B(tensorflow::DT_FLOAT,tensorflow::TensorShape());

  // I believe here is a place to feed

  std::vector<std::pair<string,tensorflow::Tensor>> inputs = {
    {A,B},}
  std::vector<Tensor> output_tensors;
  Status run_status = session->Run(inputs,
                                   {OpNameD}, {}, &output_tensors);
  return 0;
}
```

In this case, how to feed list like [1,2,3,4,5] (I feed 'list' to the same place in python) to Tensor B?
I tried to use like

```
B.vec<float>()
```

but it doesn't work. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you need to copy the values to the tensor

```
vector<int>vec_list
for(int i = 0 ; i < 5 ; ++i)
{
    vec.push_back(i+1);
}
int inputs_num = vec_list.size()
//make tensor shape {1,yure list size} this allocated the needed memory
Tensor x = Tensor(DT_FLOAT, TensorShape({1, inputs_num}));
//this flat the memory so you can copy the datat to tensor
auto flatx = x.flat<float>();
std::copy_n( vec.begin(), inputs_num, flatx.data());
```